# Error "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast" when try to transform a String to int in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm Receving this error `d[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast` when I try to tranform a String to a int. To me more especific it is a value coming from Firebase, like

```
QuerySnapshot result = await firestore.collection("video").get()

result.docs.forEach((element) {
      var ID = element.data().values.elementAt(4) // the element at this position is an ID

 });
```

I already try in many ways, transform this value to int, like:

```
int value = int.parse(ID));
```

or

```
int value = ID as int;
```

But no matter how I try it, just give mt the same error,
Thanks very much in advance

Comment: does ID contain only integers?

Comment: What is the result of `print(ID)`?

Comment: It print a "number" maybe it's just a number inside a string. I need to compare two numbers, so I need to tranform this string to int

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ID` is already `integer` and there's no need for type casting. Try `int value = ID;`

Comment: It returns  "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in where the data is coming from, that is, the firestore api.

What happen is that when you use the get() to get data from you DB the information come like this [userName, email, ID], but when you close the app, open again and try to re-call those informations, it can bring it like this: [userName, ID, email].

I really don't know why this is happining and don't know how to solv it. But I will try to filter whitch data come from the request